# How can I catch the change of a child Widget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, qwidget

I have some dynamically added QWidgets and I want to carry out some task when they are changed.
I think I can't use connect() because I also need the name of the QWidget that triggered the change.
How can I also see which QWidget was changed and still catch the value change event with a common handler?

Comment: What do you mean by 'changed'?

Comment: You're right, I have both QCheckBoxes and QSliders. They have stateChanged(int) and sliderMoved(int). Those I mean to catch.

Comment: Sorry, have no time for a detailed answer, but I think you should look at `QSignalMapper` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty way is to use connect() as usual, and then in your slot method, call sender() to find out which object sent the signal.  For example:

```
// slot method that you've connected all of your widgets' stateChanged(int) signals to
void MyClass :: someWidgetsStateChanged(int newState) 
{
   const QObject * s = sender();

        if (dynamic_cast<const QCheckBox *>(s) == _myFirstCheckbox) printf("First checkbox is now %s\n", newState?"Checked":"unchecked");
   else if (dynamic_cast<const QCheckBox *>(s) == _mySecondCheckbox) printf("Second checkbox is now %s\n", newState?"Checked":"unchecked");

   [... and so on...]
}
```

Note that the reason this is considered "dirty" is that it breaks encapsulation.  In particular, the someWidgetsStateChanged() method above now behaves differently depending on which object generated the signal, and so if e.g. at some point in the future you connected a QPushButton::clicked() (or whatever) to that same slot, you'd probably have to update the someWidgetsStateChanged() implementation to handle it appropriately.  Still, this works and doesn't require a lot of effort to implement.

Comment: I have a design flaw in my code so I went on rather doing this quick fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to catch events before they are passed to QObject subclass instances:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter

Comment: EventFilter installed too much :( it did not repaint QWidget either.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Did you remember to return false from your filter method, so events are not actually filtered?

Comment: For some reason the whole EventFilter thing does not work now. But you were right, I did leave return true as I should have not.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional thinking I arrived at saying why not to extend these controllers? 
So that I could hook them to the parent object using parent() or using a custom constructor.

It requires potentially though that I define them as friend classes...